# Zoho Integration - How to Push data To Zoho CRM in XML Format Using PHP

Tags: php, xml, zoho

I wanted to push data into Zoho CRM but their Data Format Is XML I am Able to pass one record but how to pass multiple records Actually they have API for multiple records but we can send a fixed number of records but I want to push a varying number of records.

```
        $xml_dat = '<Leads>';
$xml_dat .= '<row no="1">';

$xml_dat .= '<FL val="First Name">'.$result123456[0].'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Last Name">'.$lastname.'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Title">'.$designation1.'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Company">'.$company1.'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Mobile">'.$mobile1.'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Phone">'.$phoesplit[0].'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Other Phone">'.$phoesplit[1].'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Email">'.$email1.'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Website">'.$website1.'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Street">'.$street.'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="City">'.$city.'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="State">'.$state.'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Country">'.$country.'</FL>';
$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Zip Code">'.$postal.'</FL>';

$xml_dat .= '<FL val="Description">'.$notes1.'</FL>';


$xml_dat .= '</row>';
$xml_dat .= '</Leads>';
```

Comment: This V1 API's are deprecated. better you can use v2 API. Kindly [refer this](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/developer/api/insert-records.html) But, This is not xml format you need.

Answer (score 0):

One Of the best ways Is to Push Contacts or Leads TO Zoho CRM Is

```
$xml_data = '<Contacts>';
$xml_data .= '<row no="1">';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="First Name">'.$FirstName.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Last Name">'.$LastName.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Title">'.$Designation.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Account Name">'.$companyName.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Mobile">'.$mobileNumber.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Phone">'.$phone.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Other Phone">'.$OtherPhone.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Email">'.$EmailID.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Mailing Street">'.$Street.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Mailing City">'.$City.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Mailing State">'.$State.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Mailing Country">'.$Country.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Mailing Zip">'.$PostalCode.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '<FL val="Description">'.$Notes.'</FL>';
$xml_data .= '</row>';
$xml_data .= '</Contacts>';
```

API Url Will Look Like This

```
$Contact_Url = 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Contacts/insertRecords? 
authtoken=' . $auth_token . 
&scope=crmapi&duplicateCheck=2&version=4&newFormat=1&xmlData=' . urlencode( 
$xml_data );
```